# How to add map inside document in firestore using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using map inside array in firestore document. The problem is that when i am adding maps with new values then instead of increasing the size of array it is replacing new map with current map.
My code is look like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = {'name': "Asad"};

RaisedButton(
    child: Text("press me"),
    onPressed: () {
      Firestore.instance.collection('Shops').document('2').setData({
        'name': 'Ali',
        'id': '3',
        'array': FieldValue.arrayUnion([map])
      });
    },
  ),
```

And my firestore db looks like this:

[image]
How to increase the size of array or you can say how to add new element inside array instead of replacing it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update a document instead of overwriting its content, you should use [updateData()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/updateData.html) instead of setData().  Either that, or pass `{merge: true}` to [setData()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/setData.html) as the second argument.